# What's the relationship between Probability and Population distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to learn statistics, and I can't see how probability fits in to all of this.

Specifically, what's the relationship between probability distributions and population distributions? Are they the same?

A probability distribution is defined for a random variable, and a random variable is just a function that maps outcomes of an experiment onto the set of real numbers, right?.

So, probability distributions are  related to sample spaces of experiments.

Where do the terms "population" and "samples" fit in here? Because now I'm studying sampling theory and they're trying to make a connection between the two concepts, but I just don't get it.

Comment: If you plan to sample one value from a population, then your sample value is a random variable; its probability distribution is the population distribution.

Comment: Suppose you are trying to analyze the height of people.  Now, if we had data on the entire population, we'd know the exact probability that a person was a given height.  Of course, we can't know the entire population.  We can, however, know a sample.  That's a draw from the (unknown) probability distribution.  Using what we see from our sample, we can attempt to infer properties of the population distribution.  That's a typical goal of statistics.

Comment: @lulu does that mean that the probability distribution is a model of the population distribution?

Comment: The sample distribution is the sample distribution.  Sure,  you expect it to be closely related to the population distribution, but you don't expect it to match exactly

Comment: In statistics one has a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and a family of probability measures $\mathcal{P}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Base on observables (values of some random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$, one tries to infer which of $P$ in $\mathcal{P}$ better describes what we observed. The collection $\mathcal{P}$ is sometimes referred as the "population".

Comment: @Mittens thanks for your comment, but I didn't get what you said

Comment: @Junior: I just described in a crude way the whole paradigm of mathematical statistics; one has observations, which is modeled as values of a sequence of random variables defined in some (fixed)  measurable space; there is also a family of probability measures(which is usually referred as population) and one’s to identify which probability in the family best describes the observables (pointwise estimates) or which mixture of probabilities best described the what we observe (a Bayesian framework).

Comment: @Mittens wow. Thank you once again, but if you could please simplify it further. I'm kind of a new to statistics and probability. I'm  it taking as a 2nd year course in the university, business statistics. So if you'd be willing, please dumb it down

Answer (score 1):

Probability distributions are abstract mathematical models of random quantities, things like the "normal distribution" or the "binomial distribution".

When considering the statistical problem of making inferences about the characteristics of a entire "population" using data collected in a random sample taken from that population, it can be helpful to *assume* that the population can be described in terms of abstract probability distributions, for example that the height of individuals in the population in meters follows a normal distribution with some mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  This is the "population distribution" for heights.  What we actually *mean* by this in the context of sampling theory is that, if we take a random sample from this population and tabulate their heights, the heights $X_1,\dots,X_n$ considered as random variables will be assumed to be iid random variables with distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

In other words, the population distribution is the assumed probability distribution for the individual components of an iid random sample taken from the population.  So the population distribution is the probability distribution of the sample units (!).  Ironically, the "sampling distribution" is something else entirely!  This terminology might seem odd, but the sample is a random sample from the population, and each individual in the sample has been "drawn" from the population, and so their height follows the population distribution of heights, which we have assumed follows an abstract probability distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Is that clear?

As for the sampling distribution, once we have assumed a population distribution follows a particular abstract probability distribution to provide the mathematical foundation for our sampling theory, we can consider the distribution of a "statistic" calculated from the sample, like the sample mean:
$$\bar{X} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Under the assumption that the random sample is iid distributed according to the population distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the statistic $\bar{X}$ has a *sampling* distribution given by another abstract probability distribution:
$$X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$$

More generally, sampling theory is all about determining how the population distribution (the assumed abstract probability distribution of units sampled from the population we are trying to describe) can be mathematically related to the sampling distribution of a particular statistic (the abstract probability distribution of that sample-based statistic for a particular finite sample), and that lets us do statistics (like calculating confidence intervals or performing hypothesis tests or whatever).

One potential point of confusion is that in basic sampling theory we don't try to think too hard about the nature of the population *other* than specifying a population distribution (that is actually the probability distribution of the iid random variables of a random sample).  That is, we don't think about the population as being a finite group of individuals whose heights have a particular probability distribution themselves.  We instead just think of the population as an abstract source of iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$-distributed random variables.  If you eventually study sampling theory for finite populations, this might start to make more sense.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. But I don't fully understand. In your example about heights, did you say that the heights of the individual units of any random sample of the population are random variables? I thought a random variable was just a function of outcomes of an experiment, so how is it that the individual heights are random variables? Also, what's the experiment in this case? You said something about the population distribution being the probability distribution of the sample units. Does that mean that for every sample unit, its relative frequency in the entire population is its prob?

Comment: Your definition of random variable is technically correct -- a random variable is formally and technically a function defined on a set called the "probability space" whose elements are called "outcomes" -- but it would be wrong to think that the outcomes are the heights and only "functions of the heights" like sample means and variances can be random variables.  A better definition of random variable, taken from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is "a mathematical formalization of a quantity or object which depends on random events".

Comment: It's reasonable to consider the heights of the individuals in the sample as resulting from random events -- random genetics and environments producing the heights in the population; random sampling selecting individuals to be part of the sample.  So, the height of the first individual in the sample is a "quantity or object which depends on random events", and we can model it as a "random variable".

Comment: For your last question, note that considering the relative frequency of a particular height in the entire population and interpreting that as a probability would involve "thinking about the population as being a finite group of individuals", which isn't something we typically do.  I know that's not very satisfying -- you may want to try to formulate a follow-up question or two.

Comment: Bhur. Once again, thank you! How about this-- the probability of each sample unit of the population is its "expected relative frequency" as the sample size tends to infinity. This "expected relative frequency" is given by a population distribution, or more accurately, an abstract model of the population distribution(a probability distribution)

Comment: Bhur. I still don't get how the sample values are random variables on their own. Are they instead values of the random variable "Height" which takes each individual of the population as inputs  and gives their height as outputs. That would mean that the population is the sample space on which the random variable is defined. I'm so confused right now!!

Comment: My recommendation is to stop thinking of random variables as functions.  If you think of them as functions, you need to consider some advanced mathematical machinery to understand what the inputs and outputs actually are.  Instead, just think of them as "random quantities"; .  Since they are just random quantities and not "functions", you don't have to worry about their inputs and outputs.  The height of the first subjects in your sample is a random variable because it is a random quantity; same with the height of the second subject; and same with the mean of the whole sample.